# Having trouble with db-connection when installing Joomla 4.2.9 on Debian 11.6 using PostgreSQL 13.9

Tags: postgresql, joomla, apache2, haproxy

I am having difficulties to set up a Joomla on a Debian 11 web-server using Apache2 and PostgreSQL. The web-server is behind a reverse proxy and the PostgreSQL database is installed on another server.

My setup:

- Debian 11.6 (my web-server)
- Apache2 2.4.56
- PHP 8.2.4
- Joomla 4.2.9
- PostgreSQL 13.9 (on another server)
- HAProxy 2.2.9 (on another server)

The revese proxy I am using to expose my web-server to the sub-domain www. The config of HAProxy looks like this.

```
backend www_server
        option forwardfor
        mode http
        server www1 192.168.A.B:<PORT>/www/ check
```

The apache-config looks like this.

```
<VirtualHost *:PORT>
        ServerName www.example.com
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/joomla/

        <Directory /var/www/joomla>
                Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                DirectoryIndex index.php
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

PostgreSQL is working properly. And there are no firewall issues because I tested it.

After I setup all properly I enterd the URL: https://www.example.com/index.php and the Joomla setup is starting.
When I enter the DB-Params in  the setup form, I get permanently the error "A Database error occurred.".

Then I tried to check, if my PHP can establish a connection to my PostgreSQL on the other server. Luckilly I found the following script on StackOverflow. It's doing the job pretty well.

```
<?php
$connection = 'host=192.168.X.Y port=5432 dbname=joomla_db user=foo password=bar';
$dbconn = pg_connect($connection);
$result = pg_query($dbconn, "select * from pg_stat_activity");

var_dump($dbconn);
var_dump(pg_fetch_all($result));
```

And the script is getting me a result like this.

```
object(PgSql\Connection)#1 (0) { } array(9) { [0]=> array(21) { ["datid"]=> NULL ["datname"]=> NULL ["pid"]=> string(3) "542" ["leader_pid"]=> NULL ["usesysid"]=> NULL ["usename"]=> NULL ["application_name"]=> string(0) "" ["client_addr"]=> NULL ["client_hostname"]=> NULL ["client_port"]=> NULL ["backend_start"]=> NULL ["xact_start"]=> NULL ["query_start"]=> NULL ["state_change"]=> NULL ["wait_event_type"]=> NULL ["wait_event"]=> NULL ["state"]=> NULL ["backend_xid"]=> NULL ["backend_xmin"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(24) "" ["backend_type"]=> NULL } [1]=> array(21) { ["datid"]=> NULL ["datname"]=> NULL ["pid"]=> string(3) "544" ["leader_pid"]=> NULL ["usesysid"]=> string(2) "10" ["usename"]=> string(8) "postgres" ["application_name"]=> string(0) "" ["client_addr"]=> NULL ["client_hostname"]=> NULL ["client_port"]=> NULL ["backend_start"]=> NULL ["xact_start"]=> NULL ["query_start"]=> NULL ["state_change"]=> NULL ["wait_event_type"]=> NULL ["wait_event"]=> NULL ["state"]=> NULL ["backend_xid"]=> NULL ["backend_xmin"]=> NULL ["query"]=> string(24) "" ["backend_type"]=> NULL }
<... more data...>
}
```

This tells me, that a proper connection from my web-server to my PostgreSQL can be established with PHP. But Joomla won't install itself. After entering the connection-params in the setup-form of Joomla

[Joomla Setup Form - database part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZpjl.png)

the error "A Database error occurred." is permanently showing up.

[Joomla Setup Form - error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOhvG.png)

I'm pretty much stuck here. Can anybody help me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The database exist?
Also you can check the Postgres log to identify the Joomla connection and the result of that (maybe rejected).

Comment: Yes, the database does exist. I granted all privileges, too. What I did to create the database was: CREATE DATABASE joomla_db; CREATE USER foo WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'md*****'; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE joomla_db TO foo; The password is correct. I tested it successfully with a connection wir psql.

Comment: And there are no entries in the log whatsoever. When I enter deliberately a syntax error in psql I can find this error-entry in the log. But there are no errors from Joomla. There are only my deliberate syntax-errors.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. It indeed was an incomplete configuration of HAProxy. The right configuration looks like this.

```
backend www_server
    option forwardfor
    mode http
    server www1 192.168.A.B:PORT/www/ check
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Host %[req.hdr(Host)]
```

With this configuration all works pretty well.